# Checking for empty String for error checking

Tags: java, swing, object, methods, if-statement

Why does this method result in a runtime error? I understand the calc wont work with an empty string, so I set hour to 0 if this is the case.

Call:

```
String hoursJLabel = actionObject.calculateHours();
totalHours.setText(hoursJLabel);
```

Method:

```
public String calculateHours (){
    double sum = 0;
    double hour = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (hourArray[i].getText() != "") {
            hour = Double.parseDouble(hourArray[i].getText());
        }
        else  {
            hour = 0;
        }
    }
    sum += hour;
    return String.format("%.2f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Please show the exception stack trace.

Comment: `!= ""` is definitely _a_ problem, though it might not be _the_ problem.  Always use `.equals` to compare strings.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is supposed to be doing, but don't you want the `sum += hour` to be inside the for loop?

Comment: @David has any of our answers solved your problem or do you need further help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities where a runtime error can occur in `calculateHours()`:

- `hourArray` is `null` and throws a `NullPointerException`
- any `hourArray[i]` is null and throws a `NullPointerException`
- `hourArray[i].getText()` can not be parsed to a `Double` and throws a `NumberFormatException`
- Your `hourArray` might contains of less than 7 elements, which throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Beside that, `hourArray[i].getText() != ""` is a bad comparison because it does not check `null` and checks if the two objects are the same object, not if they are equal.

In addition, I guess you want to have `sum += hour` inside the loop, otherwise `sum` will contain the last value of the `hourArray`.

So, your method should look like this:

```
public String calculateHours (){
    double sum = 0;
    if(hourArray != null){ // hourArray might be null
        double hour = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hourArray.length; i++) { // use .length here
            // check for nulls and empty String
            if (hourArray[i] != null && hourArray[i].getText() != null 
                                     && !"".equals(hourArray[i].getText())) {
                try{ // the text might can not be parsed to a double
                    hour = Double.parseDouble(hourArray[i].getText());
                }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    hour = 0;
                }
            }
            else  {
                hour = 0;
            }
            sum += hour; // I guess you want that inside your loop
        }
    }
    return String.format("%.2f", sum);
}
```

Anyway, it would be better if this class is written in a way that it does not have to check for all this possibilities in the `calculateHours()` method. You notice how hard it becomes to read if all these checks must be done here.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a non-null `String` is empty, use `length()` method:

```
if (hourArray[i].getText().length() == 0) ...
```

If a string could be `null`, add a check *before* the length, like this:

```
String str = hourArray[i].getText();
if (str != null && str.length() == 0) ...
```

If you use Java-6 or later, you can simplify it further:

```
String str = hourArray[i].getText();
if (str != null && str.isEmpty()) ...
```

Comment: @PaulBellora That's not available until Java-6, but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

FI: Apache commons StringUtils has a method isBlank that would handle null, empty and strings with only spaces etc.,